# HTML about FLOAT

Tags: html, css

Why does this code (with the float property) show an `a` element bigger than the code without the float property?

```
<html>

   <head>

       <style>


       a {
          float: left; /* this is the property */
          height: 40px;
          line-height: 40px;
          padding-left: 0.8em;
          padding-right: 0.8em;
          border-top-left-radius: 8px;
          border-top-right-radius: 8px;
          background-image: url(images/headerTiny.png);
          background-repeat: repeat;
        }

      </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#">Box Title</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

Sorry for my English, I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 3):

That is because when you float an element, it automatically becomes a block level element (without the need to declare `display: block`). A block level element will allow you to specify both its width and height respectively.

When you remove the float property, the `<a>` element defaults to an inline element (i.e. `display: inline` by default). An inline element does not respond to width and height definitions.

You can see the code snippet below and compare the floated and unfloated versions of the same element.

```css
a {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 0.8em;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

a.float {
  float: left;
}

a.nofloat {

}
```

```html
<a class="float" href="#">Box Title (floated)</a>

<a class="nofloat" href="#">Box Title (no float)</a>
```